# Determining if a function is complex-differtiable

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The question I have been asked is: Let $g :$ \ $ \{-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the function defined by: $$g(z) = \frac{\overline{z}^2}{1+z} $$

I need to use the definition of complex-differentiation to identify the $a \in \mathbb{C}$ \ {$-1$} at which $g$ is complex-differentiable or not complex-differentiable.

This is my attempt:

To prove the complex differentiability of the function $g :$ \ $\{-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ I must show the existence of: $$\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} ( \frac{( \overline{a} + \overline{h})^2}{1+a+h})- \frac{\overline{a}^2}{1+a}$$

$$ = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} ( \frac{ \overline{a}^2 + 2\overline{ah} + \overline{h}^2}{h+h^2+ah} - \frac{\overline{a}^2}{h+ah}$$

$$ = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} ( \frac{ \overline{a}^2 + 2\overline{ah} + \overline{h}^2}{h+h^2+ah}) - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{\overline{a}^2}{h+ah})$$

Now if I look at just $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{\overline{a}^2}{h+ah})$:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{\overline{a}^2}{h+ah}) = \overline{a}^2 \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{h+ah})$$
$$ = \overline{a}^2 \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{h(a+1)})$$
$$ = \overline{a}^2 \frac{1}{a+1} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{h})$$
$$ = \overline{a}^2 \cdot \frac{1}{a+1} \cdot  \infty $$
$$= \infty$$

Therefore, for $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\frac{\overline{a}^2}{h+ah})$ approaching the limit along different directions of the real axis gives different values. Thus the global limit does not exist and therefore $\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$ does not exist either. Therefore I can conclude that $g$ is not complex differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$

That is what I have done but this is a grey area in complex analysis for me so I would be grateful if someone could confirm I am working along the right lines/ point out my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: I think that, technically, that function is complex-differentiable at $z=0$. I say "technically" because complex differentiability at a single point is a completely useless property, one has to be differentiable on an open set to get something out of it. The quick way of doing these computations is rewriting the complex differentiability property as $\partial_{\overline z} f=0.$

Comment: Thank you @GiuseppeNegro , I have to prove this directly from the definition, is that possible using the rewritten property you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the real and imaginary parts of $g$ and show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied.  That's equivalent to testing whether $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} = 0$.  If you accept all of that, it's clear this function is not complex differentiable except possibly at $0$.

If you really need to do it from the definition, then you have to show that 
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(a+h) - g(a)}{h}
$$
does not exist.  In your answer you argued that since $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(a)}{h}$ is infinite, the entire limit does not exist.  That's flawed reasoning, because the same argument applies to every difference quotient, including those of differentiable functions.

Let's simplify: why is $f(z) = \bar z$ not differentiable?  At a point $a$,
$$
   \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \frac{\overline{a+h} - \bar a}{h} = \frac{\bar h}{h}
$$
We can let $h \to 0$ in any number of directions.  For instance, if $h$ is real, then $\frac{\bar{h}}{h} = 1$, so the limit would have to be $1$.  But if $h$ is purely imaginary, then $\frac{\bar h}{h} = -1$, so the limit would have to be $-1$.  Since these both can't be true, the limit can't exist.

I suggest you try something similar here.  If $a\neq 0$, set $h=ta$ and let $t \to 0$.  Then set $h=ita$  and let $t \to 0$.  If you get different limits, $g$ cannot be differentiable at $a$.

The derivative at $0$ is equal to
$$
    \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\bar h^2}{h(1+h)} = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is making more sense to me now however I can't seem to manipulate the limits with $h=ta$ to achieve anything, is it possible for you to help some more?

Comment: Maybe L'Hôpital's rule would help?